# Interpreting ELF symbol table

Tags: c, symbols

I wrote a simple program called a.c to understand the symbol table on x86 machine:

```
extern int foo;

int function(void){
  return foo;
}
```

I compile it and readelf

$gcc -c -m32 a.c

$readelf -a a.o > a.log

The symbol table in a.log is shown below:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS a.c
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     6: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     8: 00000000    10 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 function
     9: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND foo
```

What are the purpose of symbol table entry 0 and entries from 2 to 7?

Comment: According to [the blog on elf symbol table of Ali Bahrami](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/inside_elf_symbol_tables) :

`Index 0 in any symbol table is used to represent undefined symbols. As such, the first entry in a symbol table (index 0) is always completely zeroed (type STT_NOTYPE), and is not used.`

Comment: `SECTION` may correspond to section hearders `.text` (1), `.data` (3),`.bss` (4), `.note.GNU-stack` (6), `.eh_frame`(7) and `.comment`(5). These are either PROGBITS or NOBITS (`.bss`) sections.